Getting GGML_ASSERT(!grammar->stacks.empty()) failed
I am using the Longwriter in ollama which i have customized to my needs but when i run it i am getting the following error as well as sometimes i am getting the response as !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! instead of actual content.
Here is my actual code
MODEL = "EntropyYue/longwriter-glm4:9b"
client = Client(host="http://xyz.*********")

def get_answer(query, contexts, date_context):
    system_prompt_search = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["date_today"], template=search_prompt_system)

    messages = [
        # {"role": "system", "content": system_prompt_search.format(date_today=date_context)},
        {"role": "user", "content": "User Question : " + query + "\n\n CONTEXTS :\n\n" + contexts}
    ]

    try:
        stream = client.chat(
            model=MODEL,
            messages=messages,
            stream=True,
            options={
              "temperature": 0,
            }
        )

        for chunk in stream:
            # print("chunk is", chunk)
            if chunk["message"]["content"] is not None:
                yield chunk["message"]["content"]

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during get_answer call: {e}")
        yield "data:" + json.dumps(
            {'type': 'error', 'data': "We are currently experiencing some issues. Please try again later."}) + "\n\n"


ERROR: an unknown error was encountered while running the model GGML_ASSERT(!grammar->stacks.empty()) failed
Sometimes it gives me a response like !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! instead of actual contents. I am not sure what i have to do it since i am learning the LLM's right now.
